# How to test a function that is inside of setTimeout in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, junit, chai

```
functionDoThings = function(){
    doSomethingA();
    setTimeout(function(){
         doSoemthingB();
    }, 1000);
}
```

in my test code, I have

```
testDoThings = function(){
    var ACalled, BCalled = false;
    doSomethingA() = function(){ACalled = true;};
    doSoemthingB() = function(){BCalled = true;};
    functionDoThings();
    expect(ACalled).to.be.ok; //Passed
    expect(BCalled).to.be.ok; //Fail
}
```

It is because expect(BCalled) is called too early.
How can I test the doSoemthingB gets called inside of the setTimeout()?

Comment: A proper asynchronous design would have a completion callback that tells you when the async part of the operation is done and what value or error was returned (or return a promise that serves the same purpose).  To be able to test the code you show, it needs to be fixed to return a result in a callback.  Otherwise, your testing code has no idea when it's done or what its result is.

Comment: You invoke a function even before it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've done this means that you expect BCalled to happen straight after ACalled has happened.  But, you've also said that there should be a delay of one second.

Without getting into the design, you can test it by wrapping your expect in a `setTimeout()`, too.

Also, you're assigning a value to a function call.  It should be `doSomethingA = function(){ACalled = true}`

Here is code to try, which will show you why it's not working.

```
testDoThings = function(){
    var ACalled, BCalled = false;
    doSomethingA = function(){ACalled = true;};
    doSoemthingB = function(){BCalled = true;};
    functionDoThings();
    console.log(ACalled === true); // true
    console.log(BCalled === true); // false
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(BCalled === true); // true
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `setTimeout()`, it adds your function to a stack that will be executed after the current scope. Updating your code, the expected answer will be received if you put the `expect(BCalled).to.be.ok` after call `doSoemthingB()`. It looks like:

```
functionDoThings = function(){
  var BCalled = false;

  doSomethingA();
  setTimeout(function(){
    doSoemthingB();
    expect(BCalled).to.be.ok
  }, 1000);
}
```